# use jquery validation on button click

Tags: php, jquery

I want to validate my form on button click.

For that I used `("#trade").validate();`.

But My problem is that when user click on my button so it's call one more function which post my data.

```
<input type="button" class="button" value="Save" onClick="create_trade();">
```

I used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#trade").validate();
    });
</script>
```

Now how will I validate this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After form validation, you call the function create_trade(), in the submitHandler event.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#trade").validate({
               submitHandler: function(form) {
                create_trade();
           }
         });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use form tag's onsubmit attribute.
like this `<form onsubmit="return validate()"`
This will not submit form data if the function returns true so make sure you return true only if your validation is done otherwise return false from the function so that your form data will not be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<input type="button" class="button" name="save" value="Save">
</form>
    <script>
    function fn_submit()
    {
    document.form1.submit();
    }
    </script>
```

try this....

Answer (score 0):

Try this code if you want to call the validation function on clicking the button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
        //validation code
    });
 });
</script>
```